# return from nested async method

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, eventkit

I have the following function that requests reminder permission from the user:

```
func requestAccess(alertWith viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder) { (granted, error) in

            // check wether the user granted permission
            if granted {
                // FIXME: return true
            } else {
                // alert the user they didn't grant permission
                error?.alert(with: viewController, error: .permissionFailed(error!))
                // FIXME: return false
            }

        }

    }
```

It should return the 2 bools at the FIXMEs, but using plain return doesn't work (returning non-void from void method).

Comment: Make your `requestAccess` method return void (nothing) then use the lines you have marked `FIXME:` to call other methods. You cannot use an async call to return a value in the enclosing method. Alternatively, use a completion handler. The duplicate link has solutions for this.

Comment: @Chris can I make requestAccess somehow also async and therefore return?

Comment: Yes that’s sort of what a completion handler does. You modify `requestAccess()` so it accepts a `()->Void` closure as an argument called `completionHandler`. Then you call `completionHandler()` in the `FIXME` lines.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Forgot about that.

Comment: This is all covered in the duplicate I linked earlier.